# $R^2-{0}$ is homeomorphic to $R×S^1$

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Show that $\mathbb{R}^2-\{(0,0)\}$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}×S^1.$

What I have done is the following:
Define $\phi:\mathbb{R}^2-\{(0,0)\}$ by $\phi((x,y))=(\frac{(x,y)}{||(x,y)||},x+y)$
It's injective, surjective and continuous. But I have no idea what is the inverse.

Comment: Polar coordinates.

Comment: What ? The map I have given can you give the inverse of this map?

Comment: I think you wanted to write $\phi(x,y) = (x+y,\frac{(x,y)}{||(x,y)||})$ instead of $\phi((x,y))=(\frac{(x,y)}{||(x,y)||},x+y)$ because you have written $\mathbb{R}\times S^{1}$

Comment: Start by considering the map $\eta:(0,\infty)\times\mathbb{S}^1\to\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{(0,0)\}$ given by $\eta(r,v)=rv$

Comment: How did you prove that this is injective?

Comment: How did you prove that this is surjective?

Comment: $\phi(x_1,y_1)=\phi(x_2,y_2)=>x_1=x_2, y_1=y_2$

Comment: That's just the definition of injectivity, but how did you prove that this holds for your function?

Comment: I have understood my mistake now. I don't know how to prove this is injection!

Comment: It isn't injective. $\phi(1,-1)=\phi(2,-2)=((\theta,\theta),0)$, where $\theta=1/\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: Correct . Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Define
$$ f : \mathbb R^2 \setminus \{0\} \to \mathbb R \times S^1, f(p) = \left(\ln \lVert p \rVert,\frac{p}{\lVert p \rVert}\right) .$$
Its inverse is
$$ g :  \mathbb R \times S^1\mathbb \to \Bbb R^2 \setminus \{0\}, g(x,z) = e^xz .$$

Comment: (+1) Better answer imo than those in the duplicate, because not using (cautionless!) a parametrization of $S^1$ by $[0,2\pi)$.